# Hide any images which are within the svg tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, svg

How do I hide any images which are within the inline svg in javascript?

e.g.: `<svg>.... <image src='...'> </svg>`

The purpose of this is to avoid the below X box appearing in IE when I use drawImage() to draw the svg to canvas.

[image]

Comment: plain js or with jQuery? What have you tried and where is your problem?

Comment: @Legends I'm looking for a js solution. I've tried jQ solution`$("#idof-svgImg").hide();` but did not work.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery, and have just that one svg tag, you can use the hide() function:

$("svg>image").hide();

Comment: nice... but I still get a X box appearing when I use drawImage(); see my edit.

Comment: Can you please post example of code with which that X box is still appearing?

Answer (score 0):

Simple example using just JavaScript:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Test Page</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
    </head>
    <body>

    <svg id="mySvg" width="60" height="60">
        <image id="img1" x="0" y="0" width="60" height="60" xlink:href="some.svg">
    </svg>
    <br />
    <input id="showButton" type="button" onclick="show()" value="Show" />
    <input id="hideButton" type="button" onclick="hide()" value="Hide" />

    <script language="JavaScript">
      show = function(){
        var img = document.getElementById("img1");
        img.style.display = "";
      }

      hide = function(){
        var img = document.getElementById("img1");
        img.style.display = "none";
      }   
    </script>

    </body>
</html>
```